# how to convert the unopened webpage to pdf using java?

Tags: java

I need to convert unopened web page to PDF. But i have a URL for that particular page. so how can i get that URL page as PDF file with out opened that page in java?

can any one know meet such scenario?

Comment: @Nishant : unopened means without open that web page. opened means while you are viewing that page you can convert easily right?

Comment: Your need the page contents. Java does not care if the page is seen or not on a browser. Therefore this question can be answered by the many HTML to PDF libraries you can find here or through Google.

Answer (score 1):

[YaHP Converter](http://www.allcolor.org/YaHPConverter/) should serve your purpose, some snippet code from the website

```
converter.convertToPdf(new URL(url),
        IHtmlToPdfTransformer.A4P, headerFooterList, out,
        properties);
```

Comment: for that which package i need to import?

Comment: i think just the yahp.jar will do